# 'Super' cannot be used outside of class members in XCode7 swift2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.2

Iam getting a number of errors, please help me out. I am budding developer...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrBjp.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put a closing brace `}` after the email IBOutlet which signifies the end of class scope at that line. Remove that.

Comment: Mohonish is right. Anytime you see a page full of errors like that, you've probably got an extra or missing `{` `}`